# How to Fix Azure Maps PCF Component Drawing Tools Offset

Tags: powerapps, azure-maps, powerapps-component-framework

I have an Azure Maps [PCF Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/component-framework/create-custom-controls-using-pcf) imported as a solution into a PowerApp.

- If a pin is dropped in the upper-left corner, it falls directly under the cursor (like it should).
- As I drop pins down and to the right, the pins fall increasingly further from the cursor (problem)
- This also happens when drawing vertices of polygons and origins of circles/squares

**Example:**
[image]

**Additional findings:**

1. Offset distance and direction changes depending on browser window size
   [image]
2. Inspect `div`'s
   [image]

**Where would I look in the source code to find the fix for this issue?**

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this with the drawing tools on their own. Will ask one of our devs to take a look to see if they can reproduce.

Comment: Dev took a look and wasn't able to reproduce. Can you try the following sample in the same browser to see if it reproduces for you: https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/Drawing%20Tools%20Module/Add%20drawing%20toolbar%20to%20map.html Also try your control in other browsers to see if it happens there too. One last thing, can you inspect the map div to see if a transform is being done on the map, for example, a scale transform. I've seen that cause issues with some other things before.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this issue. The sample you provided works as intended. Please see OP for more findings: 1. Offset distance from cursor changes depending on browser window size. 2. I'm not sure which `div` to inspect as many highlight the map control. One other critical item: This is a PowerApps CANVAS app, not a Model-driven app.

Comment: A canvas Power App will scale to fit the window; this could be causing the issue.

Comment: Hi @GregHurlman. Do you know how to address this in the PCF code or where I might look?

Answer (score 0):

The offset was due to the following settings. When turned to "Off", the offset disappeared:
[image]